# Heat equation with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to solve the mixed inital-boundary problem using the method of separation of variables:

$u_t = D_{xx}$

$u(x,0)=2 \sin(\frac{5 \pi x}{2L})$

$u(0,t)=0$

$u_x(L,t)=0$

I know that this problem can be rewritten as:

$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$

$u_x=X'T$

$x_{xx}=X"T$

$u_t=XT'$

so the given problem becomes:

$X(x)T'(t)=DX"(x)T(t) \Rightarrow  \frac{X"(x)}{X(x)}=D\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}= \gamma$

can we can split in 2 ODEs.

The solution for $T$ is easy $T(t)=Ce^{\gamma t}$ with C constant

I am not sure how to solve the second one because I am not sure how to apply the mixed boundary conditions

considering the case $\gamma= -\lambda^2$

$X(x) = A \cos{\lambda x} + B \sin{\lambda x}$

$X(0) = 0 \implies A \cos{0} + B \sin{0} = A = 0$

$X'(L) = 0 \implies B \lambda \cos{\lambda L} = 0 \implies \lambda L = (n+1/2) \pi$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: OK. You still have to determine $n$ with condition $u(x,0)$.